# specifying height of a paragraph

Tags: html, css

How to specify the height of the `<p>` tag?

Answer (score 6):

It's easy with CSS:

```
p 
{
    height: 100px; /*your measurement and unit*/
}
```

Since a `<p>` element is by definition block, you can assign height, width to it with no problems.

But doing it this way would make *all* of your `<p>` elements in your entire site this height.

You should select it either by its parent (`mDiv p {...` or the best way (imo) is by using a class:

```
<p class="myP">Text</p>

p.myP
{
    height: 100px; /*your measurement and unit*/
}
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

```
.pclass {
     height:200px;
}

<p class="pclass">
     some text
</p>
```